# how to calculate a ratio formula based on some conditions in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, group-by, data-analysis

I have a data frame, my data frame is like this:
except the last column is not there.
I mean I do not have formula column and here my purpose is to calculate that column.

but how it has been calculated?

the formula for the last column is: for each patientNumber, 
number of Yes/total number of questions has been answered by the patient.

for example for the `patient number one`:there is `1 Yes and 2 No`, so it has been `1/3`

for patient two, in year `2006, month 10`, we can not see `Yes` the three questions are no, so it has been calculated `0`

```
 PatientNumber           QT         Answer   Answerdate      year    month  dayofyear  count  formula
1        1          transferring     No      2017-03-03      2017       3         62      2.0   (1/3)
2        1          preparing food   No      2017-03-03      2017       3         62      2.0   (1/3)
3        1          medications      Yes     2017-03-03      2017       3         62      1.0   (1/3)
4        2          transferring     No      2006-10-05      2006       10        275    3.0    0   
5        2          preparing food   No      2006-10-05      2006       10        275    3.0    0
6        2          medications      No      2006-10-05      2006       10        275    3.0    0
7        2          transferring     Yes     2007-4-15       2007       4        105    2.0    2/3
8        2          preparing food   Yes     2007-4-15       2007       4        105    2.0   2/3
9        2          medications      No      2007-4-15       2007       4        105    1.0      2/3
10       2          transferring     Yes     2007-12-15      2007       12        345    1.0      1/3
11       2          preparing food   No      2007-12-15      2007       12       345    2.0    1/3
12       2          medications      No      2007-12-15      2007       12        345    2.0    1/3
13       2          transferring     Yes     2008-10-10      2008       10        280    1.0    (1/3)
14       2          preparing food   No      2008-10-10      2008       10        280    2.0    (1/3)
15       2          medications      No      2008-10-10      2008       10        280    2.0    (1/3)
16       3          medications      No      2008-10-10      2008       12        280    ……    ………..
```

**Update 1**

**Also, what if the formula change a little bit:**

if the patient visit the hospital `once a year`, the same formula as it is multiple by 2. for example, for year `2017` there is just one month related to that patient, so it means the patient reached just one time during the year. in this case the above formula multiple by 2 works.

```
(why because my window should be every 6 month, so if the patient has not come every 6 month I am assuming the same record is happening)
```

**But** if there is several records during one year for one patient, it should be `multiplied 2/the number of record on that year`.
for example at year `2007`, the patient reached the hospital `2 times` once in `month 4` and another in `month 12` so in this case the same formula should be multiplied by `2/2`

Comment: @Mohamed Thasin ah Thanks but No it is ok. one patient may has record in several times during the year. I am going to process according to different year and different months

Comment: If it's like that, then for patient number 2 and year 2007 should have same value (3/6). But in your output it's different

Comment: @Mohamed Thasin ah you should take into account both year and month. for 2007 year there is two month one 4 and another 12, because of that they have to be considerred seperately. thanks for following

Comment: Now I got it Ill try to solve your problem.

Comment: I appreciate it thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
def func(x):
    x['yes']= len(x[x['Answer']=='Yes'])
    x['all']= len(x)
    return x
df=df.groupby(['PatientNumber','Answerdate']).apply(func)
df['formula_applied']=df['yes']/df['all']
df['formula']=(df['yes']).astype(str)+'/'+(df['all']).astype(str)
print df
```

Output:

```
    PatientNumber              QT Answer  Answerdate  year  month  dayofyear  \
0               1    transferring     No  2017-03-03  2017      3         62   
1               1  preparing food     No  2017-03-03  2017      3         62   
2               1     medications    Yes  2017-03-03  2017      3         62   
3               2    transferring     No  2006-10-05  2006     10        275   
4               2  preparing food     No  2006-10-05  2006     10        275   
5               2     medications     No  2006-10-05  2006     10        275   
6               2    transferring    Yes   2007-4-15  2007      4        105   
7               2  preparing food    Yes   2007-4-15  2007      4        105   
8               2     medications     No   2007-4-15  2007      4        105   
9               2    transferring    Yes  2007-12-15  2007     12        345   
10              2  preparing food     No  2007-12-15  2007     12        345   
11              2     medications     No  2007-12-15  2007     12        345   
12              2    transferring    Yes  2008-10-10  2008     10        280   
13              2  preparing food     No  2008-10-10  2008     10        280   
14              2     medications     No  2008-10-10  2008     10        280   

    count  yes  all  formula_applied formula  
0     2.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
1     2.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
2     1.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
3     3.0    0    3         0.000000     0/3  
4     3.0    0    3         0.000000     0/3  
5     3.0    0    3         0.000000     0/3  
6     2.0    2    3         0.666667     2/3  
7     2.0    2    3         0.666667     2/3  
8     1.0    2    3         0.666667     2/3  
9     1.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
10    2.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
11    2.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
12    1.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
13    2.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3  
14    2.0    1    3         0.333333     1/3
```

Explanation:
Try to get help from user defined method. this func will calculate you number of yes and total record. then you could solve it as your wish. column formula is your desired result. If you want it to evaluate i added formula_applied.

Comment: Thank you so much, it working perfectly :). does Len do the same job as Count here?

Comment: do u mind if I add one more question related to this question?

Comment: It's okay you can add. I'm on travel if time permits I'll definitely solve your problem or else I'll post the answer tomorrow

Comment: I see and thanks for your time, I just updated and add a small modification. I really appreciate if you can have a look.

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - find unique for year column return length of unique elements in year and save this to new series and multiply with your old formula. Try Tolbert by yourself or else I'll update my answer tomorrow

Comment: Actually I can not do like this: data['counts']=data.groupby(['Clinic Number','year'])["month"].nunique().reset_index(name='counts') it raises error, if I do not mention name of count, my data frame will be changed and not all column are there

Comment: Try this, DF['count']=DF.groupby('year')['PatientNumber'].nunique()

Comment: do you have any idea of this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912819/how-to-combine-two-bar-chart-of-two-files-in-one-diagram-in-matplotlib-pandas?noredirect=1#comment88826203_50912819 I appreciate to have a look if you have time :)

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - Thanks for letting me know your new question. I'll definitely take a look. I'll try to solve this problem tomorrow morning and update you status :-)

Comment: appreciate it :)