# how to combine two bar chart of two files in one diagram in matplotlib pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by, data-analysis

I have two dataframe with the same columns but different content.
I have plotted `dffinal data frame`. now I want to plot another dataframe `dffinal_no` on the same diagram to be comparable.

for example one bar chart in `blue colour`, and the same bar chart with another colour just `differentiating in y-axis`.

This is part of the code in which I have plotted the first data frame.

```
dffinal = df[['6month','final-formula','numPatients6month']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['6month'])

ax=dffinal.plot(kind='bar',x='6month', y='final-formula')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax2 = ax.twinx()
dffinal.plot(ax=ax2,x='6month', y='numPatients6month')
plt.show()
```

Now imagine I have another `dffinal_no` data frame with the same columns, how can I plot it in the same diagram?

This is my first diagram which I plotted, I want the other bar chart on this diagram with another color.

[image]

so the answer of @Mohamed Thasin ah is somehow what I want, except that the right y-axis is not correct.

I want `both data frame` be based on `(6month, final-formula)` but the right `y-axis` is just showing number of patients, as an information for the user.

Actually, I `DO NOT` want the first df based on `final-fomula` and the second df be based on `NumberPatients`.

**Update1 jast as a refrence how it looks like my data frame**

```
dffinal = df[['6month','final-formula','numPatients6month']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['6month'])
nocidffinal = nocidf[['6month','final-formula','numPatients6month']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['6month'])
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_ylabel('final-formula')
ax2.set_ylabel('numPatients6month')
width=0.4
nocidffinal=nocidffinal.set_index('6month').sort_index()
dffinal=dffinal.set_index('6month').sort_index()
nocidffinal['final-formula'].plot(kind='bar',color='green',ax=ax1,width=width,position=0)
dffinal['numPatients6month'].plot(kind='bar',color='red',ax=ax2,width=width,position=1)

dffinal content

,6month,final-formula,numPatients6month
166047.0,1,7.794117647058823,680
82972.0,2,5.720823798627003,437
107227.0,3,5.734767025089606,558
111330.0,4,4.838709677419355,434
95591.0,5,3.3707865168539324,534
95809.0,6,3.611738148984198,443
98662.0,7,3.5523978685612785,563
192668.0,8,2.9978586723768736,467
89460.0,9,0.9708737864077669,515
192585.0,10,2.1653543307086616,508
184325.0,11,1.727447216890595,521
85068.0,12,1.0438413361169103,479

nocidffinal

,6month,final-formula,numPatients6month
137797.0,1,3.5934291581108826,974
267492.0,2,2.1705426356589146,645
269542.0,3,2.2106631989596877,769
271950.0,4,2.0,650
276638.0,5,1.5587529976019185,834
187719.0,6,1.9461077844311379,668
218512.0,7,1.1406844106463878,789
199830.0,8,0.8862629246676514,677
269469.0,9,0.3807106598984772,788
293390.0,10,0.9668508287292817,724
254783.0,11,1.2195121951219512,738
300974.0,12,0.9695290858725761,722
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280490/how-to-make-multiple-bar-plots-one-within-another-using-matplotlib-pyplot

Comment: Thanks for the response, Actually its very simple case compared with mine. but I will give it a try and let you know :)

Comment: @inspired_learner thanks for the response, sadly I could not apply that sample to my case. mine is with pandas and I already have two axis. please let me know if you need more information. cheers to the response

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to compare two data frame result with bar plot one way you could try is concatenating two data frames and adding `hue`.
For example consider below df it contains same x and y columns in both df's and wanna compare this values. to achieve this simply add hue column for each df with differentiating constant like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y':[10,2,454,121,34]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':[4,1,2,5,3],'y':[54,12,65,12,8]})
df1['hue']=1
df2['hue']=2
res=pd.concat([df1,df2])
sns.barplot(x='x',y='y',data=res,hue='hue')
plt.show()
```

The result should looks like below:

[image]

**To get two y-axis try this method,**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylabel('final-formula')
ax2.set_ylabel('numPatients6month')

width=0.4

df1=df1.set_index('x').sort_index()
df2=df2.set_index('x').sort_index()

df1['y'].plot(kind='bar',color='blue',ax=ax1,width=width,position=1)
df2['y'].plot(kind='bar',color='green',ax=ax2,width=width,position=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**with actual input:**

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylabel('final-formula')
ax2.set_ylabel('numPatients6month')


width=0.4

df1=df1.set_index('6month').sort_index()
df2=df2.set_index('6month').sort_index()

df1['final-formula'].plot(kind='bar',color='blue',ax=ax1,width=width,position=1)
df2['numPatients6month'].plot(kind='bar',color='green',ax=ax2,width=width,position=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173415/discussion-between-mohamed-thasin-ah-and-saria-goudarzi).

Comment: while your answer really helped me I still need it in a way it should have the both y-axis. so I am unmarking your answer as the desired answer in the hope someone help me with that part

Comment: I see thanks for that. however I think its not possible to have the right y-axis as I was explaining becaz of ratio, 10/1000 is the same as 1/100, so if two bar are the same according to left y-axis, they might not be the same in the right, so I changed my mind to show each numberofPatients on above each bar, Is it possible?