# customize the color of bar chart while reading from two different data frame in seaborn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I have plotted a bar chart using the code below:

```
dffinal['CI-noCI']='Cognitive Impairement'
nocidffinal['CI-noCI']='Non Cognitive Impairement'
res=pd.concat([dffinal,nocidffinal])

sns.barplot(x='6month',y='final-formula',data=res,hue='CI-noCI')
plt.xticks(fontsize=8, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

the result is as below:

[image]

I want to change the color of them to red and green.
How can I do?
just as information, this plot is reading two different data frame.

the links I have gone through were with the case the dataframe was only one data frame so did not apply to my case.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use matplotlib to overwrite Seaborn's default color cycling to ensure the hues it uses are red and green.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = ("cycler('color', 'rg')")
```

---

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [1,2,3,4,4,5], 
                   'value': [10,15,35,14,18,4],
                   'hue_v': [1,1,2,1,2,2]})

# The normal seaborn coloring is blue and orange
sns.barplot(x='date', y='value', data=df, hue='hue_v')
```

[image]

```
# Now change the color cycling and re-make the same plot:
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = ("cycler('color', 'rg')")
sns.barplot(x='date', y='value', data=df, hue='hue_v')
```

[image]

This will now impact all of the other figures you make, so if you want to restore the seaborn defaults for all other plots you need to then do:

```
sns.reset_orig()
```

Comment: Thats Awesome, thank you so much:) do you mind if I ask a question related to plot right here or in chat. I promise it ll be a short one :)

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi yeah sure, Though I might not be able to answer it until morning.

Comment: thanks alot. this is link of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912819/how-to-combine-two-bar-chart-of-two-files-in-one-diagram-in-matplotlib-pandas. but he did not answer exactly what I meant as he understood in other way. in summary, according to the plot you even see in the question here, I want two y-axis. one in the left which is pretty ok. I want one more in the right which shows number of patients. it is only as information how many patients has been in the test. I do NOT want to have the left axis for one df and the right axis for another df2. am I clear?